# Adjacency List Graph implementation - Reusable classes

Tags: c#

I'm storing Graph (in my Graph class) as an:
`Dictionary< Vertex<T>, List<Vertex<T>> _edges`.

How should I store properties like weight, color etc. of edge? (to make it reusable for instance for `WeightedGraphs`, `ColoredGraphs` etc.) To create generic Graph class I thought about adding `IGraph` interface (which will contain common Graph operations like `Traverse`, `InsertEdge` etc.) as property in Graph class.

However I have no idea how to deal with edge properties. If I implement `IGraph` interface as `ColoredGraph` I'd like to have Vertex with color property, for `IGraph` implemented as `WeightedGraph` I'd like to have weight property and so on. I'd also like to hear how would you implement Graph as adjacency list.

ps: it's not school homework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Edge ={2 Vertices = {Adjacent Vertices per a vertex}, weighted value, color value, etc}`

THen

```
public Vertex
{
//get adjacent list of vertices
}
public class Edge
{
//define necesary values
//define pair of vertices to make an edge
}
```

Comment: I thought about Edge class but when i define weight, color, etc. some values may be unused in some cases (isn't it 'code design failure'?) Is there no other way to achieve it?

Comment: @fex Not really,  if there are such cases you could foresee then make their getters and setters polymorphic, you couold think about IGraph, there could also be IVertex, IEdge as many as you wish; all just to decouple your classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this by utilizing a `Tuple<>` as the vertex of the graph. The `Tuple<>` would allow you to store various properties of the edge.

The signature of the graph could be defined as:

```
Dictionary< Vertex<T>, List<Tuple<T, T>> _edges.
```

The first item in the `Tuple` indicates the destination node for the edge. The rest of the items in the `Tuple` would hold the properties of that edge.